# Google account integration like in Fedora 21

Tags: google, gmail

In Fedora 21 there is a great google account integration available (mail, calendar), which works with OAuth2 integration. Is there a similar possibility in Ubuntu 14 ?

Thanks.

Comment: Fedora has not been called "fedora core" for a long time now. You can integrate with google, but not in exactly the same way. See http://www.itworld.com/article/2698080/enterprise-software/add-or-configure-online-accounts-in-ubuntu-14-04.html "Fedora core" was renamed to Fedora in 2007, almost 8 years ago - http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Releases/HistoricalSchedules#Fedora_7_.28Codename:_Moonshine.29

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? What (level) of integration are you looking for? If it's application specific integration, then there's a high chance that the same application is present in the Ubuntu repositories as well, just not installed by default.

Comment: Ok, I've changed it to Fedora 21. I search integration just for Gmail and calendar. I've seen that in Fedora 21 Evolution is used with OAuth2 login. I don't see this possibility in Ubuntu (would have to lower the security level of my Gmail account, which I do not want to do). Is the OAuth2 capability bound to Gnome ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can get it by using the [GNOME environment](https://askubuntu.com/a/65223/178596) in Ubuntu (I do, or Xfce). This the one Fedora defaults to ([Ubuntu GNOME](http://ubuntugnome.org/) does as well), except Fedora usually has a much newer version *(I prefer 3.8 or 3.14 - (though 3.10 and 3.12 are easiest to get in Ubuntu)*.

You can [install Gnome 3.14](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/10/how-to-install-gnome-314-in-ubuntu.html), but it will probably break things (such as Unity) and some bits I think are missing.

But you should still have roughly the same setup - go to Settings > Online Accounts:

[image]

You probably can get a similar result with the default nity desktop, but I can't check because I uninstalled Unity on my Ubuntu machines :)

Also Ubuntu has [`evolution`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/evolution) and [`geary`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/geary) available, both of which I think can sync with GMail without the desktop being integrated as well.